Supabase / PostgreSQL: Next.js Query is still timing out after applying indexes
I have this application that is in Next.js for the frontend/backend, Supabase for the database.
I'm running this query on my reviews table:
SELECT review_image, review_description, review_title, rating_stars, review_author, helpful, reviewed_at
FROM reviews
WHERE type = 'Car'
ORDER BY sku ASC, helpful DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 8 OFFSET 0;

This is the index I've applied to it:
CREATE INDEX idx_reviews_type_sku_helpful ON public.reviews USING btree (type, sku, helpful DESC);

This is the query plan I get when I run it:
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                       |
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Limit  (cost=21.02..21.82 rows=8 width=396) (actual time=1.214..1.215 rows=8 loops=1)                                                                                            |
|   ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=21.02..100710.01 rows=1000658 width=396) (actual time=1.213..1.213 rows=8 loops=1)                                                                 |
|         Sort Key: sku, helpful DESC NULLS LAST                                                                                                                                   |
|         Presorted Key: sku                                                                                                                                                       |
|         Full-sort Groups: 1  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB                                                                                |
|         Pre-sorted Groups: 1  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Average Memory: 32kB  Peak Memory: 32kB                                                                               |
|         ->  Index Only Scan using idx_reviews_type_sku_helpful on reviews  (cost=0.55..56846.32 rows=1000658 width=396) (actual time=0.081..1.062 rows=301 loops=1) |
|               Index Cond: (type = 'Car'::text)                                                                                                                            |
|               Heap Fetches: 185                                                                                                                                                  |
| Planning Time: 22.106 ms                                                                                                                                                         |
| Execution Time: 1.847 ms   

This is the query plan after I drop the index and re-apply it.
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                   |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Limit  (cost=21.22..22.06 rows=8 width=396) (actual time=147.749..147.751 rows=8 loops=1)                                                                                    |
|   ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=21.22..101625.43 rows=965343 width=396) (actual time=147.747..147.748 rows=8 loops=1)                                                          |
|         Sort Key: sku, helpful DESC NULLS LAST                                                                                                                               |
|         Presorted Key: sku                                                                                                                                                   |
|         Full-sort Groups: 1  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB                                                                            |
|         Pre-sorted Groups: 1  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Average Memory: 32kB  Peak Memory: 32kB                                                                           |
|         ->  Index Scan using idx_reviews_type_sku_helpful on reviews  (cost=0.43..59306.77 rows=965343 width=396) (actual time=1.190..147.176 rows=301 loops=1) |
|               Index Cond: (type = 'Car'::text)                                                                                                                        |
| Planning Time: 21.310 ms                                                                                                                                                     |
| Execution Time: 147.856 ms      

This is the query plan after I use VACUUM
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                   |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Limit  (cost=21.26..22.10 rows=8 width=399) (actual time=114.537..114.540 rows=8 loops=1)                                                                                    |
|   ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=21.26..101756.74 rows=959284 width=399) (actual time=114.535..114.537 rows=8 loops=1)                                                          |
|         Sort Key: sku, helpful DESC NULLS LAST                                                                                                                               |
|         Presorted Key: sku                                                                                                                                                   |
|         Full-sort Groups: 1  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB                                                                            |
|         Pre-sorted Groups: 1  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Average Memory: 32kB  Peak Memory: 32kB                                                                           |
|         ->  Index Scan using idx_review_type_sku_helpful on reviews (cost=0.43..59703.11 rows=959284 width=399) (actual time=1.563..113.774 rows=301 loops=1) |
|               Index Cond: (type = 'Car'::text)                                                                                                                        |
| Planning Time: 3.248 ms                                                                                                                                                      |
| Execution Time: 114.642 ms 

Is this a problem on Next.js side? I'm running the same query here:
export default async function CarPage() {
  try {
    reviewData = getProductReviewsByPage(
          { productType: "Car" },
          {
            pagination: {
              page: 0,
              limit: 8,
            },
            sort: [
              { field: 'sku', order: 'asc' },
              { field: 'helpful', order: 'desc', nullsFirst: false },
            ],
          }
        )
  } catch ...
  return (
    <Car review={review}/>
  )
}

I get this error message:
[getProductReviewsByPage] caught:  {
  code: '57014',
  details: null,
  hint: null,
  message: 'canceling statement due to statement timeout'
}

Here's a snippet of the Supabase javascript:
      let fetch = supabaseDatabaseClient
        .from(PRODUCT_REVIEWS_TABLE)
        .select(
          'review_image,review_description,review_title,rating_stars,review_author,helpful,reviewed_at'
        )
        .eq('type', "Car")
        .range(from, to)
        .order(...)


Is there something I can do optimize my query more?
Or is this something that's on Next.js side that I need to adjust?
The table I'm querying against has 1mill records.
Some things I've thought about:

Clustering
Partitioning the table
Try to increase timeout?
Load the reviews after the page loads and add retries

